# How likely it is that a hacker spoofed my own IP address when trying to log in to a website?

Tags: ip, ip-spoofing

I got a confirmation code without trying to log in which is what prompted me to investigate this. The account is just a Ubisoft account with 1 free game on it; I somehow doubt there would be motivation to employ sophisticated hacker techniques.

I know about Tor services and VPN, but I don't think those would spoof my own IP address. When I look at the log-in history for my account, it says my very own IP (at least, an IP with the same first and last segment, as the middle two were obscured into "XX"), failed a login attempt 15 minutes ago and I definitely don't remember doing anything remotely related to that account in the last 12 hours. Did a hacker actually spoof the correct IP, or is this more likely some sort of bug? How would they even know the right IP to spoof in the first place

Edit: Home router, not public place

Comment: Very unlikely. Most likely someone have the same first and last segments of your IP... Even more likely is a bug on Ubisoft side, it would not be unheard of...

Comment: Or the hacker is in your own network either by being expected part of the network or by hacking some system in the network and thus is using your own external IP address.

Comment: Does "_at least, an IP with the same first and last segment_" mean the middle two numbers were different, or that Ubisoft obscured them?

Comment: When you say, "**My Own IP Address**," what are you referring to? Is this the public IP of your home router, or are you perhaps using a public access point like a business, school, or library?

Comment: Thanks, yes Ubisoft obscured the middle two numbers with "XX". It's my home router, not a public place. Updated question details

Answer (score 2):

While it's technically possible to **hijack** an IP address, it's a pretty high bar and not readily done.

I say *hijack* as opposed to *spoof* because user/client generated IP spoofs while easy are not useful for TCP or any two way communication. If I spoof your IP address as the source in my IP packet, the server will respond to that IP which will be **you** not me and I will not get a connection.

There are two fundamental ways to hijack an IP.

The simplest for an individual is to place themselves directly in-line with your connection as a Man in The Middle (MiTM), but even this can be fairly difficult in most circumstances.

The other method is via a change to Border Gateway Protocol. This is the protocol where various router gateways around the world declare that any IP addresses in a defined range should be sent to them for re-distribution. A BGP change could send your IP (*and many others*) to somewhere else in the world for subsequent handling by someone else in an IP hijack or a remote MiTM.

Both of these scenarios are pretty unlikely unless you are a high profile target.

The most likely cause is a mistake, or another device/person on your home network.

Comment: BGP hijacks are also noisy and (fairly) easy to detect.

Comment: Worth clarifying that another person may include a hacker on the OPs computer. The most straight-forward way to have someone else's IP address is to make their device perform the request for you (although that may be unlikely in this particular case)